RLDS/CofC: Angels and Theophanies
The Restoration of All Things includes a restoration of revelation. Joseph Smith, as a dispensational head, had many revelations, including visions, theophanies, angelic visitations and, of course, revelations from the Holy Spirit.
These things have continued unabated since his death in 1844, at least in the Church of JESUS CHRIST of Latter-day Saints (LDS). The entries in the RLDS/CofC D&C or the history of the RLDS are a bit less clear. The LDS church emphatically declares yes, they all continue. Wilford Woodruff (the principle source of church history from the time Joseph Smith organized the church until his death and to the days of Brigham Young, had a comprehensive vision having to do with the dead. After Woodruff's death, Lorenzo Snow had two impressive revelations — one in the Salt Lake Temple, when Jesus Christ appeared to him with instructions on how to proceed after President Woodruff's death.
Then there were others including fairly recent appearances by former church authorities. There also are other church authorities who have had theophanies, but who haven't told the general church membership.
These authorities haven't told the general church membership their stories because the incidents are none of their business and would only serve to titillate the sensitivities of those who would find them thrilling to listen to. (And there are those who would sneer at them in the retelling.) The brethren do not cast their pearls before swine. But as someone who has read the RLDS D&C, I've yet to read any “revelation” therein that indicates that they have actually experienced an honest-to-goodness revelation. Instead, they have a boatload of weasel words aimed at getting around the truth.
But if anyone knows of any experience of any church president between the death of Joseph Smith and the present woman president-prophet, I'd love to hear about it. As it is, I don't see any reference to prophets in the revelatory sense on the CofC website.

Hi John Roberts, welcome to the site. In looking at your recent questions--I may be wrong--but I don't believe there are any members of the Community of Christ (formerly the RLDS church) that are active on this site, so you may not be able to get too many answers from their perspective here.

Also, the purpose of the site is not to attack other faiths. Yes, some site users do this regularly to The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints because they think by weight of numbers they can disregard facts, decency, or rules (aka mob mentality), but that doesn't make it a good idea. All the mob mentality accomplishes is to drag down the credibility of the site.

I had several good RLDS friends in 1987 and  they were teetering on the edge of leaving their church over the political correctness issue that seemed to be replacing the first principles of the gospel. I've had these questions rolling around in my head for years, but can't find the answers. Too  bad they've vanished here. Thanks!

@JohnRoberts I think your question can (and should) be reformulated to be less confronting and attacking. From your question, I am now too somewhat interested in the perspective on the Kirtland temple, for example, but that question shouldn't be an attack, it should be an attempt to learn.
